# Personal email in comments for CPT

Tags: wordpress, comments

I have a snippet that when a user write a comment, send an author email.

But I need that it happens only when some comment in a Custom Post type. ¿How change this code in my case?

````
$comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
$post_ID = $comment->comment_post_ID;
$author_ID = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_ID );
$user_info = get_userdata($author_ID);
$email = $user_info->user_email;
$pTitle = $comment->post_title;
$cAuthor = $comment->comment_author;
$cContent = $comment->comment_content;
$cUrl = get_comment_link( $comment_id );

$to = $email;
$subject = '¡Tu examen, "'.$pTitle.'", ha sido corregido!' ;
$headers[] = 'Desde: mi email';
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8';

ob_start(); 

include("template/email_header.php");
?>

<p>Ya te tienes tu examen corregido <?php echo $pTitle; ?>. Esta es tu nota y comentario:</p>
  <p><?php echo $pTitle; ?></p>
  <p><strong>Comentario:</strong><br>
    <?php echo $cContent; ?></p><br><br>
  <p>Si necesitas volver a intentarlo vuelve a enviar el audio desde aquí. <strong><a href="">Volver a repetirlo</a></strong><br>
      
<p><strong>Singerfit</strong><br>
<?php 
include("template/email_footer.php");
$message = ob_get_contents();
$message = stripslashes($message);
ob_end_clean();

//return $message;

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

}

add_action('comment_post', 'notify_postauthor_comment', 11, 2);```
````

Answer (score 0):

get post type of a post ID `get_post_type( $post_ID );`. You can set conditions based on the post type.